# Error: The constructor is undefined

Tags: java, constructor, undefined, spring-tool-suite

I cannot understand why does the program keep telling me I have a mistake 'The constructor Date() is undefined' in code line 4. I was using it in Spring Tool Suite,but that doesn't matter I guess.
Please,can someone explain what to do and how. If it's possible write the correction and do explain. Thanks in advance!

FYI,I know it is probably a stupid question,but I am a beginner.

```
@RequestMapping("/date")
public String date () {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);

}
```

Comment: Which `Date` are you importing? Or is this class or some other class in the package called `Date`?

Comment: Date is depricated replaced by Calendar but still it should work. What "Date" do you import? Should be java.util.Date, right?

Comment: @AndyTurner Do you mind hammering the dup?

Comment: Please search the site before asking questions. A search for "Java Date constructor" immediately gave the answer.

Comment: @user1803551 I've looked for it. As I've said in my question I'm a beginner,didnt even know what to search for and didnt see anything about imports. Generally didnt know imports can mess things up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have imported `java.sql.Date;` instead of `java.util.Date;`

Just change your import to :

```
import java.util.Date;
```

If you use **eclipse** be careful because when you organize your import the first proposed class is `java.sql.Date`

Comment: YES! Thank you! But why did it import the wrong one? It keeps happening...

Comment: @SoniaEaton http://blog.vogella.com/2009/04/01/eclipse-organize-imports-filter/

Answer (score 1):

You imported the wrong class.

Just check your header and replace `import java.sql.Date;` by `import java.util.Date;`

Comment: These are the imports I have.
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

Comment: @SoniaEaton Instead of `java.sql.Date` use `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Oh,thank you a lot!